# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'wait'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, expected-condition

```
from behave import when, then, given
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

SIGN_IN_POPUP_BTN = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#nav-signin-tooltip .nav-action-inner')

@when('Click Sign In from popup')
def click_sign_in_popup_btn(context):
    e = context.driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(SIGN_IN_POPUP_BTN))
    e.click()

@then('Verify Sign In page opens')
def verify_sign_in_page_opens(context):
    assert 'https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin' in context.driver.current_url, f'Url {context.driver.current_url} does not include https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin'
```

Comment: *My question is why am I getting this error below:
  File "features\steps\sign_in.py", line 11, in click_sign_in_popup_btn
    e = context.driver.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(SIGN_IN_POPUP_BTN))
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'wait'

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The error message

```
'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'wait'
```

is telling you that 'WebDriver', your `driver` in the code below,

```
e = context.driver.wait.until(...)
            ^
```

does not have an attribute `wait`. Simply put, `WebDriver.wait`, or in your case `driver.wait`, does not exist. The syntax for using waits is in [the python docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

In this case, your code should be

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def click_sign_in_popup_btn(context):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    e = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(SIGN_IN_POPUP_BTN))
    e.click()
```

or more simply

```
def click_sign_in_popup_btn(context):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(SIGN_IN_POPUP_BTN)).click()
```